# CombineLatestWith with pipe operator is ginging error: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, []>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators, combinelatest

I was using combineLatest in my project which is working fine. But now it got deprecated. So i was looking for alternate solution. I am trying with "combineLatestWith". But it doesn't accept pipe operator and giving below error:

> Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown,
> [unknown, string, number, boolean]>'

Any reason why I am not able to use pipe operator with combineLatestWith?? Below is my code:

```
    export class TestService implements OnDestroy {
      private _viewName$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
      public depth$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(2);
      public graphMode$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    
      private _loadSubtree$(rootId: string, showGlobalLoadingIndicator: boolean = false): Observable<OprTreeGridItem<CI>[]> {

         //Below line has the error
          return combineLatestWith(this._viewName$, this.depth$, this.graphMode$).pipe(
          tap(() => this._isSubtreeLoading$.next(showGlobalLoadingIndicator)),
          switchMap(([viewName, depth, graphMode]) => this._topViewGraphHttpService.getTopViewGraph(viewName, depth, -1, rootId, null, graphMode).pipe(
            catchError(() => of([]))
          )),
          map((topViewGraphDto: TopViewGraphDTO) => topViewGraphDto.graph),
          withLatestFrom(this._viewName$, this._pickedCis$.pipe(startWith([])), this.includeViewAsRoot$),
          tap(([nodesAndRelationsDto, viewName, pickedCis, includeViewAsRoot]: [TopViewGraphNodesAndRelationsDTO, string, CI[], boolean]) => {
            console.log("something")
          }),
          map(() => {
           // some code
          })
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: [`combineLatestWith`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/combineLatestWith) is an operator. You're looking for the function [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest). Replace your `combineLatestWith` with `combineLatest([this._viewName$, this.depth$, this.graphMode$])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/combineLatestWith), `combineLatestWith` is an rxjs/operator function which returns an `OperatorFunction` and not an `Observable`

The correct rxjs function that you are probably looking for here is `combineLatest` which accepts an array of Observables and returns a new Observable